# does logs of php exec command exist?

Tags: php, security, logging, exec

I would like to know where to find log files with commands executed with a php exec function.
Did that exist or all passed commands are not stored ?

in case of compromited server, can we look at the commands executed ?

thanks

Comment: As far as I know, exec() doesn't store any kind of logs. My suggestion is to create a logging system yourself that saves the executed commands in a database, file, or whatever kind of storage you desire.

Comment: ok thanks, but I can intercept any php file using exec command ? 
cause in case of hack the command comes from a "new" file